# how to Use both staggeredgridlayoutmanager and linearlayoutmanager in same adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to use both staggeredgridlayoutmanager and linearlayoutmanager in same Recylerview Adapter as shown below in figure?

[image: Layout Design]